# Is there a reason the reported timing of my audio callback from SDL kinda follows this weird pattern?

Tags: c, linux, audio, sdl

I have this very basic example of generating two saw waves using SDL2. It seems to work fine, in that it sounds the way I expect it to sound. However, When I print out the time between callbacks, the intervals are far from being the even intervals I was expecting. Is there a reason for this?

Here is the output showing some format data and then a few dozen of the intervals:

```
want:
 freq    : 48000
 format  : 33056
 channels:     2
 silence :     0
 samples :  1024
 size    :     0

have:
 freq    : 48000
 format  : 33056
 channels:     2
 silence :     0
 samples :   512
 size    :  4096

41
 0
 0
12
 6
18
17
 0
18
12
 0
17
18
 0
17
12
 0
18
17
 0
17
12
 1
17
17
 1
12
17
 0
17
19
 0
12
17
 0
18
17
 1
11
18
 0
17
12
 0
18
18
 0
17
12
 0
17
18
 0
17
12
 0
18
17
 0
 6
18
17
 0
12
17
 1
17
17
 1
11
18
 0
17
 7
17
17
 1
11
18
 0
17
12
 0
18
17
 0
17
12
 0
19
12
 0
16
18
 0
18
12
 0
    etc...
```

Here is the code:

```
/* 
* compiled with:
*   gcc -Wall twosaw.c -o twosaw `sdl2-config --cflags --libs`
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include "SDL.h"

#define AudSamRat 48000
#define AudBufLen  1024

Uint32 lastTime;
Uint32 thisTime;

float phaseL = -1;
float phaseR = -1;
void fillAudioBuffer(void *unused, Uint8 *byteStream, int byteStreamLength)
{
  //printf("byteStreamLength: %d\n", byteStreamLength); //-> 4096

  float* floatStream = (float*) byteStream;
  Uint32 floatStreamLength = byteStreamLength/4; //-> 1024

  thisTime=SDL_GetTicks();
  printf("%2d\n", thisTime-lastTime);
  lastTime  =thisTime;

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i<floatStreamLength; i+=2)
  {
    floatStream[i]   = phaseL; //left
    floatStream[i+1] = phaseR; //right
    phaseL += 0.01;
    phaseR += 0.02;
    if (phaseL > 1) phaseL = -1;
    if (phaseR > 1) phaseR = -1;
  }
}

void logSpec(SDL_AudioSpec *as)
{
  printf(
    " freq    : %5d\n"
    " format  : %5d\n"
    " channels: %5d\n"
    " silence : %5d\n"
    " samples : %5d\n"
    " size    : %5d\n\n",
    (int) as->freq,
    (int) as->format,
    (int) as->channels,
    (int) as->silence,
    (int) as->samples,
    (int) as->size
  );
}

int main(void)
{
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO | SDL_INIT_TIMER);

  SDL_AudioSpec want, have;
  SDL_AudioDeviceID AudDev;

  SDL_zero(want);
  want.freq = AudSamRat;
  want.format = AUDIO_F32;
  want.channels = 2;
  want.samples = AudBufLen;
  want.callback = fillAudioBuffer;

  AudDev = SDL_OpenAudioDevice(NULL, 0, &want, &have, SDL_AUDIO_ALLOW_FORMAT_CHANGE);

  if (AudDev == 0) {
    printf("Failed to open audio: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    return 1;
  } else {

    printf("\nwant:\n");
    logSpec(&want);
    printf("have:\n");
    logSpec(&have);

    if (have.format != want.format)   // we let this one thing change.
      printf("We didn't get Float32 audio format.\n");

    SDL_PauseAudioDevice(AudDev, 0);  // start audio playing.
    SDL_Delay(3000);                  // let the audio callback play some sound for 3 seconds.
    SDL_CloseAudioDevice(AudDev);
  }

  SDL_Quit();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SDL_GetTicks(), which you're using for your timing, calls GetTickCount() under the hood in Windows. GetTickCount() has a granularity of about 10-25ms (depending on who you ask), which means it's more or less useless for this application.

I do have to wonder though, what are you trying to determine by looking at when your callback gets called? If you really need to know, take a look at the QueryPerformanceCounter API under windows. Or, if you're lucky enough to be using modern compiler, use std::chrono.

Using QueryPerformanceCounter...

```
// only need to do this part once
LARGE_INTEGER Freq;
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Freq);

// Then, for timing
LARGE_INTEGER Time;
QueryPerformanceCounter(&Time);
double TimeInSeconds = double(Time.QuadPart) / double(Freq.QuadPart);
```

Using std::chrono

```
// at the start. chrono uses intervals, and wants a start time (I think)
auto StartTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

// during
std::chrono::duration<double> fsec = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - StartTime;
double TimeInSecondsSinceStart = fsec.count();
```

Comment: Or you can use [the portable high-resolution timer API in SDL2 itself](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetPerformanceCounter).

Comment: Very good point. Also I think my answer might possibly be quite wrong in any case, since a slightly closer reading shows that the question is almost certainly about a Linux machine.